# the type or namespace name 'mixedreality' does not exist in the namespace 'microsoft' (are you missing an assembly refrence?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am currently developing an app for the Hololens 2 with Unity and mrtk. I am trying to get the Gaze direction from the GazeProvider.cs which is attached to the camera, because i want to spawn objects in front of the players face. I am trying to access it like the mrtk site states:

```
void LogGazeDirectionOrigin()
{
    Debug.Log("Gaze is looking in direction: "
        + CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.GazeDirection);

    Debug.Log("Gaze origin is: "
        + CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.GazeOrigin);
}
```

However when trying to `using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;` the error

> the type or namespace name 'mixedreality' does not exist in the namespace 'microsoft' (are you missing an assembly refrence?)

occurs. Therefore CoreServices is also not recgonized. Also i recognised, that the GazeProvider.cs hat this path in the package folder *Packages/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation/Services/InputSystem/GazeProvider.cs*. I don't know how to fix this or how to access the gaze direction of the player, i have been searching for a while now.

I would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: Try installing Nuget package microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation. I'm guessing, but on a quick search of nuget, it looks the most likely?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get acces to the toolkit you probably have to install the package from the nuget package manager. Check out this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio) to see how you can include it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, but it unfortunately did nothing for me. I had to create a complete new project and migrated some prefabs i used there. Something with the Assemblies was broken and not created right. Some of the mrtk packages probably generated new assamblies, but i do not know which one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I’m Wayne Wang from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team!

Here is my suggestion:

- make sure you are using latest "Mixed Reality Feature Tool" to install packages dependencies as "Local tarball"
- Go to the unity menu: "Edit" ->"Preferences" ->"External Tools". It was the place you can change your visual studio versions.
- You may see a list with checkbox looks like this [List of checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gurXz.png)
- Make sure the generation of "Local tarball" was selected

after the setting was saved, the pacakge you referenced may create new projects in your project of C#. These projects actually can be references of your current major project. The errors should be gone by then.

Answer (score -1):

File→Build Settings→Play Settings→As shown below
in OtherSettings

[image]

Change it to the one that is different from the original, ctrl+s save
can try it, thank you